# Interval expression in hql

Tags: java, sql, hql

I am trying to launch this sql with hql and it doesn't work due to '* interval' expression.

The sql calculates the avg in 5 mins intervals.

How could be changed the sql to make it works with hql?

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', update_timestamp) + (( cast (date_part('minute', update_timestamp) as int) / 5) +1) * interval '5 min' AS minute
      ,  sum(t.free_spaces) as orders_count
FROM  myTable t
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Hql does not support `interval`. You have to use `between`. 
If you want, you can also use native query.

Comment: Right, but the query must calculate the avg every 5 mins. The between command won't be useful in this case

Comment: You can calculate it in java and put into between query, isn't possible?

Comment: Yes, but i would like to calculate all 5 mins periods grouped by 5 mins interval in one query

Answer (score 0):

you can use the make_interval function.

I found out that it works with HQL Queries,
You can define the parameter like that :

> make_interval( NUMBEROFYEARS )

> make_interval( days = NUMBEROFDAYS )

You can refere to this web site for more about make_interval :
https://pgpedia.info/m/make_interval.html